# group array of objects with inner array of strings javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group

I have an array of objects like below -

```
const books = [
  {
    name:"abc",
    isbn: 123,
    tags: ["tagA","tagB","tagC"]
  },
  {
    name:"xyz",
    isbn: 456,
    tags: ["tagB","tagC"]
  },
  {
    name:"pqr",
    isbn: 456,
    tags: ["tagB"]
  }
];
```

I want to group it based on `tags` of each object, and push the matched objects into the `tags` values which is string array. My expected output shoulb be an object having the grouped value as key and the value should be the array of matched values.

My Expected Output is-

```
const expected = {
    "tagA" : [
     {
         name:"abc",
       isbn: 123,  
     },
  ],
    "tagB" : [
     {
         name:"abc",
       isbn: 123,  
     },
     {
         name:"xyz",
       isbn: 456,  
     },
     {
         name:"pqr",
       isbn: 456,  
     },
  ],
    "tagC" : [
      {
         name:"abc",
       isbn: 123,  
     },
     {
         name:"xyz",
       isbn: 456,  
     },
  ],
}
```

Comment: maybe show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: This is just a standard group-by with an added loop to add each element to multiple groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very standard 'group by' with an extra loop to add each element to multiple groups.

Here using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to isolate the `tags` array from the rest of the `book` object, iterating over each tag creating a property in the result using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) if it doesn't already exist, and then pushing a clone of each `book` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const books = [{ name: "abc", isbn: 123, tags: ["tagA", "tagB", "tagC"] }, { name: "xyz", isbn: 456, tags: ["tagB", "tagC"] }, { name: "pqr", isbn: 456, tags: ["tagB"] }];

const result = {};
for (const { tags, ...book } of books) {
  for (const tag of tags) {
    (result[tag] ??= []).push({...book});
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are similar questions for grouping by key value; since you want to group based on value of key which is array, you could do something like this:

```js
const books = [
  {
    name:"abc",
    isbn: 123,
    tags: ["tagA","tagB","tagC"]
  },
  {
    name:"xyz",
    isbn: 456,
    tags: ["tagB","tagC"]
  },
  {
    name:"pqr",
    isbn: 456,
    tags: ["tagB"]
  }
];

let grouped = {};

books.forEach((book)=>{

 book.tags.forEach(tag=>{
   if(!grouped[tag]) grouped[tag] = [{name:book.name,isbn:book.isbn}]
   else grouped[tag].push({name:book.name,isbn:book.isbn})
 })

})

console.log(grouped)
```